# jQuery - select change()

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
<div id="displayData_length" class="dataTables_length">
  <label>
     Show <select name="displayData_length" size="1" aria-controls="displayData">
             <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
             <option value="25">25</option>
             <option value="50">50</option>
             <option value="100">100</option>
           </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

When I select option I want use alert() and display value. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=displayData_length]').bind('change', function(event) {
            alert(this.val());
        });
 });
```

But is not good, what is wrong?

Comment: can you set a breakpoint? Is the alert line being hit? What is the actual problem? You may want to do `alert($(this).val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
$('select[name=displayData_length]').bind('change', function(event) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

In jQuery event handlers, `this` always points to DOM element, not wrapped with jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7YJpV/ - see this demo. Code is copy/pasted from your question. Only change - `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()`

Answer (score 1):

`.val` is a jQuery function, and `this` is just a DOM Node. You need to access `$(this).val()`, or `this.value`

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap **this** with jQuery object

Change this

```
  alert(this.val());
```

to

```
 alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap `this` in jQuery object.

```
$('select[name=displayData_length]').bind('change', function(event) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

also note, that this selector is faster

```
$('select', '#displayData_length') // faster
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `this` in a jQuery object:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$('select[name=displayData_length]').change(function() {
     alert($(this).val());    # for value
     alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());   # for text (UPDATED)
});
```

Comment: `$(this).text()` will not work. You will have to use `$(this).find('option:selected').text()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<select name="displayData_length" size="1" aria-controls="displayData" id="dia">
<option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>  

<script>
$("#dia").change(function () {
     var selctedValue = "";
     $("select option:selected").each(function () {
     selctedValue += $(this).val();
    alert(selctedValue);
    });
});
</script>
```